# Отсутствуют библиотеки в c# консольном приложении на ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

Я пытаюсь запустить консольное приложение, которое содержит в себе телеграм бота. Делаю я это через чистую консоль Ubuntu на Proxmox, через mono. При команде `csc Program.cs` мне выводится ошибка о том, что нету библиотеки:

```
Program.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Telegram' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Telegram' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Telegram' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(20,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ITelegramBotClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(20,64): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Update' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(39,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ITelegramBotClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(12,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TelegramBotClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно у вас возникли проблемы с зависимостями. Вы можете сделать это с помощью NuGet.

Поскольку вы используете Mono, вам нужно будет использовать NuGet для установки пакетов. Вот как это сделать:

Установите NuGet, если у вас его еще нет:

```
sudo apt-get install nuget
```

Создайте файл packages.config в каталоге вашего проекта с таким содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Telegram.Bot" version="17.0.0" />
</packages>
```

Замените 17.0.0 на желаемую версию библиотеки, если вам требуется другая версия.

В каталоге вашего проекта выполните следующую команду, чтобы установить зависимости:

```
nuget restore
```

Теперь, когда библиотека установлена, вы можете скомпилировать ваш проект, указав сборки в качестве ссылок:

```
csc Program.cs -r:./packages/Telegram.Bot.17.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Telegram.Bot.dll
```

Проверьте, что путь к файлу Telegram.Bot.dll указан верно. Если всё сделано правильно, ваш проект должен скомпилироваться без ошибок.

Comment: dotnet build, не? зачем руками эти ссылки прописывать?